# Theta time complexity for loop

Tags: math, for-loop, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity, big-o

What would be the time complexity for this kind of loop in theta notation?

> for (j=1; j< n^3 ; j=3*j)

Is it logn^3?

I understand independently when to use logn and when to use n^x but when combining them together, I seem to have an issue understanding the outcome.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right.
But note that

```
Log(n^3) = 3 * Log(n)
```

so complexity is `Theta(Log(n))`, because constant factor doesn't affect on asymptotic behavior.

Comment: is that the same in big theta notation?

Comment: Yes. Here is theta really (we know tight bounds)

Comment: Isn't it more exactly (3/Log(3))*Log(n) (which doesn't affect the validity of your answer in Theta notation)?

Comment: Yes, it is more exact. I used author's expression `logn^3` with omitted constant.